# Merging column headers in a gridview wth textboxes in cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need help with merging a grid view columns especially with textboxes in cells:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Calibri" 
    Font-Size="Small" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblItem" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Item") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RowNum">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRowNum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RowNum") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UnitName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUnitName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UnitName") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AgreementNum">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgreementNum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AgreementNum") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contractor">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtContractor" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Contractor") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Budget">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBudget" runat="server"  Width = "50" Text='<%# Eval("Budget") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

The last threes column headers should be merged under "Description" column.
As I searched a lot with no success. I would appreciate an example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting the last 3 textboxes into the same itemtemplate. Searching is good, what have you tried? It would be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding how to ask good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemTemplate` allows you to put any HTML or ASP controls in it. You can merge them by putting the three ASP textboxes in it. Optionally, you can separate them by line breaks `<br />`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgreementNum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AgreementNum") %>' />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtContractor" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Contractor") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBudget" runat="server"  Width = "50" Text='<%# Eval("Budget") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```